# How to get max value in the column whilst counting and then reset count after reaching 0 and start to count until other max value is reached

Tags: excel, count, numbers, max

I am trying to get the max value per run from my table. Each run lasts a different amount of days hence there will be a different max value for each run. My current table column Days looks like this:

```
Days:
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
0
1
2
3
4
5
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
0
1
2
3
```

I have another column called Max Day, where I want to get the max day per run from the above Days column, this is the output that I **want** to get at the end:

```
Max Days:
8
5
11
3
```

I have tried doing:
=COUNTIF(A$1:A1, A1) but that doesn't do anything, it just returns 0. Is there a way I can get the max value and then when it reaches 0, it starts counting again and retrieves the max value for that count and then repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Office 365, this is a piece of cake with the new Filter() function. In the screenshot, the formula has been entered into cell C2 and has NOT been copied down. It does that automatically.

```
=FILTER(A2:A31,A3:A32=0)
```

[image]

**Edit** - Explanation. For a general understanding of the new Excel Dynamic Array functions, please refer to this [blog by the Excel team](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/preview-of-dynamic-arrays-in-excel/ba-p/252944).

The Filter function returns all rows that match a given criterion. In this case the range to be filtered and the range in the criterion are offset by one row. The filter looks at rows 2 to 31, but the comparison looks at rows 3 to 32.

The effect is that the filter returns a value when the comparison is TRUE for the NEXT row, not the current row. Hence, the function returns all rows where the row FOLLOWING the current cell contains a zero.

Comment: @teylin Brilliant! And upvoted. But would you please explain how it works?

Comment: @Variatus -- as you wish. Edited.